# Formation of a planet with a mercury core

Tags: science-based, planets, solar-system

Building on [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27297/likelihood-of-a-magnetosphere-with-a-mercury-core) about the magnetosphere for a planet with a substantial mercury core, *what is the proto-planetary environment required to form a planet with a mercury core?*  Specifically, I'm looking for initial conditions to the [protoplanetary disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protoplanetary_disk) in terms of elemental composition, not the process by which planets form from that disk.  Assume that a star does form and is stable enough to support planet formation.

Details about crust composition/formation and details of life on such a planet are out of scope.  Also, if this planet ends up being made partly of gold, that would be interesting too. Speculate if you please, but it's not required.

Comment: The Earth is partly made of gold.

Answer (score 6):

## You want a cold disk.

Mercury is an example of a [*volatile*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatiles), which, for our purposes, means that it exists as a solid only at very low temperatures. One thesis ([Funk (2015)](http://kups.ub.uni-koeln.de/6150/)) classifies it as "moderately volatile" (Table 1.1), also noting that its *50% condensation temperature*, $T_{c}$<sup>1</sup>, is less than that of sulfur. It is, in fact, around 250 K. That is really, really, really low. For a graphical comparison, see Figure 2 of [Albarede (2009)](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v461/n7268/pdf/nature08477.pdf?origin=ppub).

Therefore, abundances of Mercury in the center of the protoplanetary disk were very low ([*Evolution of Earth and its Climate*](https://books.google.com/books?id=QHbeAq8YeXoC), page 64). The thing is, that's where terrestrial planets form - inside the [frost line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frost_line_%28astrophysics%29) (though there should be regions inside the frost line where mercury can still condense). Sure, there's *some* mercury there - after all, we have it on Earth, and some of that likely formed with the planet - but not nearly enough to create an entire planetary core.

Therefore, you need a *really* cold planetary disk. [HL Tauri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HL_Tauri) appears to be a possibility. [Carrasco-Gonzalez et al. (2016)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.03731) found a temperature of $\sim70\text{-}140\text{ K}$ at 10 AU. Given that temperatures in disks roughly obey a power law<sup>2</sup> of
$$T(r)=T(r_o)\left(\frac{r}{r_o}\right)^{-q}$$
and $q=0.5\text{-}0.6$, then if we take the lower temperature bound, we find that $T(1\text{ AU})$, for instance, can be $221\text{ K}$, which would seem to work. There still might not be enough mercury for a whole core to form, but one can hope.

---

<sup>1</sup> $T_c$ is the temperature at which 50% of all the mercury is condensed.

<sup>2</sup> In general, [disks around Sun-like stars follow a power law](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2*arctan(10000%2F140000)+in+arcminutes) of
$$T(r)\propto\left(\frac{r}{1\text{ AU}}\right)^{-q}\left(\frac{M_*}{M_{\odot}}\right)$$
where $M_*$ is the mass of the star and $q>0$. The proportionality constant is probably somewhere in the range of $200\text{-}300\text{ K}$; these slides give it as $280\text{ K}$.